# Obtaining the key of an array that matches certain criteria works only for the zero key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this loop that is supposed to return the key number that matches certain criteria (where md5 of several inner keys match a string reported by client).

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$response->count.$element->text) ) {
        break;
    }
    elseif ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$postData['num'].$element->text) ) {
        $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" saved with less accuracy (another comment added before it was saved)';
        $this->wh_log($log_msg);
        break;
    }
    else {
        $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Couldn\'t save the comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" sent from '.$ip.' because it failed the integrity check';
        $this->wh_log($log_msg);
        return $this->save_level2($access_token, $response, $referer);
    }
}
echo 'level 1 $key is '.$key.' || ';
```

The problem is that during further testing, it turned out that if it doesn't find the meeting condition in the zero key (`$response->posts[0]`), then it immediately proceeds with the last condition (defined in `else`) and creates a logfile with an error, without even trying to find the meeting condition in other keys such as 1, 2, etc. And my echo function says `level 1 $key is 0`, while it's supposed to echo the key that meets the condition. But it seems like it doesn't go beyond the zero key for some reason.

// I edited the code so that it doesn't contain the variables that people wouldn't acknowledge.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: By the way in the `if` and the `elseif`, this `echo 'level 1 $key is '.$key.' || ';` won't be executed since it's after a `break;`

Comment: No problem, that's not the issue right now (but I'll edit). There's no error. I'm just not getting the proper key number. It doesn't check other keys besides `$response->posts[0]` for meeting my criteria.

Comment: I'll try to explain better. It's supposed to return the number of the sub-array that contains the values whose md5 is equal to a string from the client. However, it the very first sub-array (i. e. `$response->posts[0]`) doesn't contain such values, then it doesn't check other sub-arrays and immediately proceeds with the condition defined in `else`, while it only must run if there's no matching values in ANY array (but there ARE such values in another sub-array, just not in`$response->posts[0]`, but in `$response->posts[1]`).

Comment: Also, it always echoes `level 1 $key is 0`, even when it was supposed to break at another key. P.S. I made a mistake in this example but I reverted the position of the echo function to where it originally was (correctly).

Comment: Yeah, just got that point

Comment: `return` will immediately end the function (if inside a function) or script/file (otherwise). and it will return regardless of being in a loop or not. so the first time your `else` branch is executed, the loop ends due to `return`, in all other branches it ends due to `break`

Comment: after a long bike ride and some thoughts. I think I figured out a meta-problem: the solutions so far answer your question (why only key zero), but don't solve your problem. now, you have two conditions (the formulas in your if/elseif respectively). now apparently you have to tell us, which of the following you actually want to achieve: option A: you want the *first* key, for which *either* condition is true, B: you want the +first* key, for which *both* conditions are true *simultaneously*, C: you want something else (please describe). (maybe the last key, or some successive keys?)

Comment: `if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$response->count.$element->text` - if this condition is true, I must get the number of the first key that meets it. If none of the keys meets this conditions, then the key number must be obtained from this condition: `if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$postData['num'].$element->text)`. Finally, if none of the keys meet both conditions, the last `else` statement shall be executed. I hope this clarifies everything.

Comment: it does. I'll revise my answer ;o)

Comment: and my answer is revised.

Comment: I decided to exclude that logic from my project at all, but I will test it later to see if my solution really didn't work with the second `if`.

Answer (score 0):

first, for correctness sake, the answer to the original question "why is only the first key considered" (paraphrased) is still:

`return` will immediately end the function (if inside a function) or script/file (otherwise). and it will return regardless of being in a loop or not. so the first time your `else` branch is executed, the loop ends due to `return`, in all other branches it ends due to `break`

however, to solve the underlying problem:

The problem to solve is: 
find the first key that matches condition 1, if there is none, find the first key that matches condition 2, if there is none, output some generic stuff (error output).

There are many ways to solve this problem, where the main difference is, whether the loop is run once or twice. Since you identified your conditions already, I'll just call them `$cond1` and `$cond2` respectively:

```
$cond1key = $cond2key = null; // <-- this stores what we'll find
foreach($response->posts as $key => $element) {
    if($cond1) {
         // if we find a key, for which $cond1 is true, we can abort
         $cond1key = $key;
         break;
    } elseif(!$cond2key && $cond2) {
         // if we find a key, for which $cond2 is true, there still
         // may be a key, for which $cond1 is true, so no break.
         // also notice the !$cond2key in the if statement, this 
         // prevents overwriting
         $cond2key = $key;
    }
 }
 // now we look at the results of our "search"
 if($cond1key) {
     // key found by condition 1
     echo 'level 1 $key is '.$cond1key.' || ';
 } elseif($cond2key) {
     // key found by condition 2
     $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" saved with less accuracy (another comment added before it was saved)';
     $this->wh_log($log_msg);
 } else {
     // no key found
     $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Couldn\'t save the comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" sent from '.$ip.' because it failed the integrity check';
     $this->wh_log($log_msg);
     return $this->save_level2($access_token, $response, $referer);
 }
```

now, I used only a single loop there, the repeated loop would also be possible (now very much simplified code):

```
 foreach($response->posts as $key => $value) {
     if($cond1) {
          $cond1key = $key;
          break;
     }
 }
 if(!$cond1key) {
     foreach($response->posts as $key => $value) {
         if($cond2) { // no danger of overwriting, since we break ...
             $cond2key = $key;
             break; // since we're only looking for a cond2 key now.
         }
     }
 }
 // conditional code execution as before
```

Now, this code is as straight forward as I can put it. There are slightly more elegant solutions, which provide no real benefit in terms of understanding, this is absolutely not meant to win any contests ;o)

Note: `$cond1key` / `$cond2key` are obviously bad names, if you have names for these variables that are semantically more appropriate, use those.

Hope this helps ;o)

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be. The point is that my `else` shouldn't be executed in the first place. Because I know for sure that matching values are present in another key, just not in `[0]`.

Comment: Let me try to explain in even more detail... If this function doesn't find the matching values in `$response->posts[0]`, then it must iterate over other keys, such as `$response->posts[1]`, `$response->posts[2]`, etc, until it finds the matching values in some of them. Then, it must return the number of the key in which the values match. But it never iterates over other keys... So it only can find matching values in `$response->posts[0]` and doesn't check other keys, even when the zero key doesn't contain matching values (if it did, then it would be expected behavior).

Comment: that is exactly what I said, it cycles through the posts, and that cycling will STOP as soon as `break` or `return` is encountered, which it is, right at $key=0. there is no parallelization or anything.

Comment: But my `key 0` doesn't meet the `if` condition, so why would it stop at it?

Comment: It's supposed to break only `if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$response->count.$element->text) )`; But at key 0, this condition is not met. Only one of the other keys meets that condition. And yet it breaks at zero.

Comment: `return` "breaks" too (just way more than the `break`)

Comment: Where do you see a `return`? It's only in `else` part, and it mustn't reach that part if it finds a match. And I know there is a match.

Comment: in the loop, the `if`, `elseif` then `else` are evaluated. *first* this happens for key 0, where it breaks, afterwards - **if the loop would still be going, which it is NOT** - it would evaluate for key 1 and so on. the loop breaks on first iteration.

Comment: That's exactly the issue! It mustn't break at key 0 because key 0 doesn't satisfy the `if` statement!

Comment: what do you believe does `else` mean? it executes, if the `if` isn't satisfied.

Comment: But it must execute only if there's no matches in all keys, however, some of them matches, it just doesn't search all keys for some reason.

Comment: then it's at the wrong place. set a `$found=true` somewhere, and check after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not Iterating over the values($elements)... It will always exit after one iteration:

- If condition one is **true** -> will break the loop = **no iteration**.
- If condition two is **true** -> will break the loop = **no iteration**.
- If both are **false** -> will return = breaks the loop and exits the function = **no iteration**.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do - Based on your question you expect the iteration to break when one of hashes is equal otherwise continue to iterate -> Re-think of using those breaks & return, I think you want to use something else like `CONTINUE`.

**Example:**

```
//Consider this example inputs based on your question:
$secret = "bla";
$date = "00:00:0000";
$num  = 1;
$postData = [
    "example sign1" => md5($secret.$date."postdatahere with date"),
    "example sign2" => md5($secret.$num."postdatahere with num"),
    "date"  => $date,
    "num"   => $num
];
$posts = [
    "key1" => ["text" => "postdatahere with date"],
    "key2" => ["text" => "postdatahere with num"],
    "key3" => ["text" => "will exit the loop"]
];

//Run -> check_postdata is the function containing the logic:
echo check_postdata($posts, $postData, $secret, "example sign1")."\n";
echo check_postdata($posts, $postData, $secret, "example sign2")."\n";
```

**Simplified Example 1 using your methodology:**

```
//Using this logic with the BREAKs:
function check_postdata($posts, $postData, $secret, $example) {
    foreach ( $posts as $key => $element ) {

        //Same as the md5 part:
        $correct_value_date = md5($secret.$postData["date"].$element["text"]);
        $correct_value_num = md5($secret.$postData["num"].$element["text"]); 

        if ( $postData[$example] === $correct_value_date ) {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> break in IF block!\n";
            break;
        }
        elseif ( $postData[$example] === $correct_value_num ) {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> break in ELSEIF block!\n";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> continue in ELSE block!\n";
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
/*  The Result is:
 *
 *  -  key1 -> break in IF block!
 *  1
 *  -  key1 -> continue in ELSE block!
 *  0
 */
```

**Simplified Example 2 using** `CONTINUE`:

```
//Using this logic with the CONTINUE:
function check_postdata($posts, $postData, $secret, $example) {
    foreach ( $posts as $key => $element ) {

        //Same as the md5 part:
        $correct_value_date = md5($secret.$postData["date"].$element["text"]);
        $correct_value_num = md5($secret.$postData["num"].$element["text"]); 

        if ( $postData[$example] === $correct_value_date ) {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> break in IF block!\n";
            break;
        }
        elseif ( $postData[$example] === $correct_value_num ) {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> break in ELSEIF block!\n";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "  -  ".$key." -> return in ELSE block!\n";
            continue;
        }

    }
    return "Returned key is: ".$key;
}
/*  The Result is:
 *
 *    -  key1 -> break in IF block!
 *  Returned key is: key1
 *    -  key1 -> continue in ELSE block!
 *    -  key2 -> break in ELSEIF block!
 *  Returned key is: key2
 */
```

As you can see using the your logic make no sense since it will always Iterate once and stop.
Using the `CONTINUE` method will iterate until one of the condition is true.

Hope I helped..

Comment: "Based on your question you expect the iteration to break when the two hashes compare don't match " - actually, it's the other way around what I need. I thought I clearly defined the issue...

//I'm still reading the examples though.

Comment: I changed breaks to `continue`. It didn't change anything. When I refer to `$key` after this loop, it always returns `0` and not the key where it was supposed to break. And it still doesn't break after the correct key.

Comment: @ErikGordon I Edited the Examples -> look at example 2 (my suggestion) it now iterates until it finds the correct first entry...

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't include my `else` part (I didn't want to continue on `else`), so I wrote my own answer that completely addresses the issue. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue. I had to make a variable that's only being set if a match is  found. Also, I had to continue the loop each time when it doesn't find a match. I thought it would be continued anyway, until the condition is satisfied, but I was wrong. Here's the working solution:

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$response->count.$element->text) ) {
        $key_obtained = $key;
        break;
    }
    else continue;
    if ( $postData['sign'] == md5($api_secret.$postData['date'].$postData['num'].$element->text) ) {
        $key_obtained = $key;
        $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" saved with less accuracy (another comment added before it was saved)';
        $this->wh_log($log_msg);
        break;
    }
    else continue;
    if ( !isset ($key_obtained) ) {
        $log_msg = date('H:i:s').' Couldn\'t save the comment "'.$postData['last_comment'].'" sent from '.$ip.' because it failed the integrity check';
        $this->wh_log($log_msg);
        return $this->save_level2($access_token, $response, $referer);
    }
}
echo 'level 1 $key is '.$key.' || ';
```

Comment: are you aware, that your second `if` is never evaluated at all?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a tech kind of guy and I have problems understanding programming logic. Just doing a hobby project. So please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: my advice would be to describe your problem with an extensive example, that describes what you're looking for. because as far as I can tell, none of the solutions (including mine) answers the *underlying* problem, but in fact answers some interpretation of your question. so, when describing your problems, there are usually multiple cases you want handled. try to simplify your example to show all cases. like, "my input is a list [1, 2, 3, 4], i first want to check, if there is a 2, then I want to check if there's a 4 afterwards" or something, at least that's how I understand your answer...

Comment: of course, not being *a tech kind of guy* makes things more difficult. it usually helps to spell out your assumptions of what your code should do (maybe in more detail, depending on the questions you get in return or if the answers don't solve your problem), and what it is doing instead. and this is way easier, the more you simplify your problem. (some people get hung up on the wrong details)